# Do speed bonuses stack with each other?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Do speed bonuses stack with each other in Pathfinder? For example: does a Monk's *Fast Movement* stack with the Bloodrager's *Fast Movement*?

Answer (score 8):

It all depends on the type of bonus.

For example a monks bonus is an enhancement, so it does not stack with haste. Bloodrager is untyped so it will stack with everything.

Comment: but do they stack with eachother?

Comment: @thomas Yes. In this case the two speed bonuses stack.